# Add a Year to a Month and Day in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset where some of the entries in the date column do not have years and I need to add the year 2016:

- So some of the entries will say something like this: "Apr 11"
- Other entries will say something like this: "11 Apr 2015"

For those entries that don't contain a year (of which there are many and which span a variety of different dates), I would like to add the year 2016.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to paste 2016 for elements that contain only month and day.  Match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by two digits (`\\d{2}`) that we capture as a group (`(...)`) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with space followed by the backreference of the capture group (`\\1`) followed by space and `2016`.

```
sub("\\s+(\\d{2})$", " \\1 2016", str1)
#[1] "Apr 11 2016" "Apr 11 2015"
```

---

Based on the update in the OP's post, we can also use `lubridate` to convert to 'Date'

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date(parse_date_time(str2, c('md', 'dmy')))
#[1] "2016-04-11" "2015-04-11"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Apr 11", "Apr 11 2015")
str2 <- c("Apr 11", "11 Apr 2015")
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, Thank you for the input. I tried it but it didn't work. I copied and pasted your code and then substituted the column "data$date" for "str1." I noticed that I had mistakenly put the wrong information in the original post. The entries that have years are written "date month year" rather than "month date year" (please see my amended question). Is that why your code isn't working for me?

Comment: @tlev  If you parttern is differrent, it gives me `sub("\\s+(\\d{2})$", " \\1 2016", str1)
#[1] "Apr 11 2016" "11 Apr 2015"`

Comment: @tlev I updated the post.  Check if that helps

Comment: that works! thanks!